Angular RxJS recipe to cancel previous http request
I have an Angular Service where when I select a new item, I set that item ID in my service and use that to make multiple sub calls to GET the sub-parts of the item. The code looks like this
set item(myItem: Item) {
    this._item = item;
    this.selectedItemUpdate.next(this._item);

    this.getItemSubPartOne(this._item.id);
    this.getItemSubPartTwo(this._item.id);
    this.getItemSubPartThree(this._item.id);
}

......

getItemSubPartOne(id: string) {
    let url = ...
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(
         (res:Result) => {
         this.itemSubPartOneUpdate.next(res);
     }
}

Given this pattern, what would I need to do to reconstruct this in the case where one of the sub parts has not returned, but the user has selected a different item. I will need to cancel all previous http requests.

You can easily declare three observables that start with the emission of the selected item and then return the relevant sub part data.  You do not need separate Subjects for this.
itemSubPart1$ = this.selectedItem$.pipe(
  switchMap(item => this.httpClient.get(`/item/${item.id}/sub-part-1`))
);

With the above code, we declare itemSubPart1$ to be an observable that will emit the value of the http get call whenever selectedItem$ emits a value.  switchMap has the behavior of cancelling the current call when a new emission is received.
You would simply declare your other two observables exactly the same way with their relevant urls.
Ideally, the setter would only push a value through the observable and not do any other work:
set item(myItem: Item) {
  this.selectedItem$.next(item);
}

Instead of using this._item, you could use the async pipe to alleviate the need to explicitly subscribe:
<pre *ngIf="selectedItem$ | async as item">{{ item | json }}</pre>


This other answer goes into more detail about declaring observables with specific behavior.
